# How to let a photo uploader know which photo I am replacing with?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a bunch of photos, each one of them has a name. I put one (hidden) input element (type:file) to upload an image as the following:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
     <img class="images" src="a.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4">
     <img class="images" src="b.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
<input type="file" id="my_file" class="hidden" />
```

if you clicked on one of the images it will open the system window to let you choose a file. I used JQuery to do that as the following:

```
 $(".images).click(function() {
        $("input[id='my_file']").click();
 });
```

How to let PHP upload a new photo instead of the selected photo, give it the same name as the selected photo (a.jpg or b.jpg) and then delete the old photo from the server. So I am gonna use one photo uploader so it knows which photo I am replacing with.

I hope my description is clear,
Thank you.